Update failed (could not execute systemctl)
I tried updating through the Software Updater, and I got this error:

Setting up liborc -0.4-dev-bin (1:0.4.38-1ubuntu0.1) Setting up systemd (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ... Setting up udev (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up libudev-dev: amd64 (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up librbd1 (19.2.0-git20240301.4c76c50-0ubuntu6.1)
Setting up libuno-cppu3t64 (4:24.2.5-0ubuntu0.24.04.2) ... Setting up systemd-oomd (255.4-1ubuntu8.2)
Setting up libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3t64 (4:24.2.5-0ubuntu0.24.04.2) Setting up liborc -0.4-dev: amd64 (1:0.4.38-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up systemd-resolved (255.4-1ubuntu8.2) ...
Setting up snapd (2.63+24.04ubuntu0.1) ...
Could not execute systemctl: at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 148. snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting
it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not start
ing it.
Failed to restart snapd.mounts-pre.target: Operation refused, unit snapd.mounts -pre.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse man ual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.mounts-pre.target' for details.

I tried a few things, but I don't want to do too much, as I'm a newbie to Linux, and I would rather not accidentally break my laptop. :)

Re-opening the Software updater. It just gets stuck on the progress bar. I tried pressing closing the window, and I get this:


Pressing continue gave me yet another error, this time about the software index:

Running sudo apt-get install -f gives me:
jacob@jacob-IdeaPad-Flex-5-14ITL05:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for jacob: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 77310 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Going back to the software updater, pressing partial upgrade asks for my password, so I assume it's not a good idea? I'm not entirely sure, but I'd rather be safe until I get confirmation from someone more experienced.
If it helps at all, since updating LibreFox (my browser, a Firefox fork) gives me this message:

Also, what might have caused this? Does something like this happen normally, or did I mess something up?
Update
My computer was sitting for an hour or so, and I came back to a comment, so I tried it again before troubleshooting that issue. I ran the sudo apt-get install -f command, and it worked this time for some reason, and there were 0 to upgrade! There were also a few to autoremove, so I did, and they were autoremoved. There were also 2 not upgraded. I went back to the Software Updater, and it said that something along the lines of the connection failing. I tried turning off a few PPAs, and I got past that issue, but then it said that I need to restart to finish the update. Not sure if that's a great idea. Back to the 2 not upgraded, I did sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, and
jacob@jacob-IdeaPad-Flex-5-14ITL05:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  file-roller gnome-text-editor
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Pretty sure it's unrelated.
Also, LibreWolf still shows the same message. Not entirely sure if it's related, but it just started, so it might be.

I would not recommend doing the "partial upgrade", they tend to break your system. The install -f didn't work because you still had some other software installer running, only one can run at a time. That is what the lock file is for. Suggest shutting down all programs and trying it again. Can't speak to the cause because it's snap related and I don't do snaps.

tried again, and it worked this time? not really sure how that happened, but I'll take it. Do you think it would be safe to reboot? (I updated my question with a few more details)

The messages you show in your last update are of no concern, so if the install -f all worked, you should be good to reboot or whatever.

It worked, thank you for your help!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site not a discussion forum. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the answer inside the question. Use the Answer Your Own Question button below to answer your question. Then after the mandatory waiting period accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as correctly answered and help others.

For some reason, after like an hour, sudo apt-get install -f worked? Not really sure how that happened, but I'll take it. I rebooted, and everything seems to work. I went back to the Software Updater, and it says that everything is up to date. I have a feeling that something will be broken, but for now, everything seems mostly fine. The LibreWolf notification is still there though.
